# An easy riddle, for once. I'm a hot girl!

Tags: riddle

This is the easiest riddle I've written yet. Have fun!

*I'm a hot girl! 

I'm twenty-six. 

If you give me water, 

I'll flatten you!*

What am I?

Comment: This is a great demonstration that a riddle can be good while being short and/or easy. Multiple meanings with wordplay are squeezed into a few lines, and every word counts.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You are:

> *An* iron (not simply iron)

I'm a hot girl!

> Iron Maiden? Indeed, an iron for clothing is normally hot.

I'm twenty-six.

> The 26th element on the periodic table is Iron (Fe).

If you give me water, I'll flatten you!

> You put water in your iron and spray water on the clothing or whatever and use it to de-crease your clothes. :)

Comment: To quote Oblongamous ... give that man a sandwich!

Comment: mmmm delicious sandwich until I recover from all that cyanide

Comment: Iron Maiden is a nice touch but not intentional ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I think it could also be

> an old hot-air balloon

Explanation:

> I'm 26: It's an *old* balloon.
>  Hot, water: If you give it water, you could put out the fire, and it will come down and crush you.
>  Girl: Ships and other modes of transportation are often referred to with feminine pronouns.

Comment: But hot-air balloons are just canvas and hot air (I think), so if you put out the fire and it fell, it wouldn't flatten you!

Comment: The basket, of course. That's a lot heavier. ;)

Comment: But if *you* "give me water" and put out the fire, you must be in the basket.

Comment: I have an answer for everything :-p

Comment: No, you can give it indirectly, like setting a timer to dump it out.

Comment: Anyway the basket isn't hot, so if "I'm a hot girl", then the basket can't be part of 'me'. Ha!