# I'm 26, what am I? - riddle

Tags: riddle

I'm 26
I'm usually cool
Sometimes I am hot, steaming hot
The Male me have a shining heart and can fly
The Young female me is, however, horrible and brings a lot of pain

What am I?

Comment: First time I've seen a riddle that's almost a dupe - check [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/5451/5373) out!

Comment: Easy: you're 26.

Comment: My guess is that it's funnier than both 24 and 25.

Comment: Ironic, the score of this question is 26...

Comment: I downvoted so the score is 26, I'm sorry. :P

Comment: @You might be the first downvote that actually made me giggle a bit

Comment: I had to downvote again. Srry. I gave you a favorite to recompense

Comment: @bleh lol next time I'll make a question starts with 'I'm 1000'

Comment: @PythonMaster You must not paste answers as comments ;)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Well, you must be

> Iron!

I'm 26

> The element Iron has an atomic number of 26.

I'm usually cool

> Iron is a metal, typically cold to the touch.

Sometimes I am hot, steaming hot

> I expect this is referring to an iron that you would use to iron clothes, which are incredibly hot.

The Male me have a shining heart and can fly

> This is clearly Iron Man, who has his suit featuring the glowing core and the ability to fly with thrusters!

The Young female me is, however, horrible and brings a lot of pain

> Well I'm guessing this is referring to Iron Maiden, but I don't know why they're so horrible - they do sing about painful stuff, though. (Or maybe I'm just stupid and this is referring to the torture device, which is clearly both horrible and painful. Thanks dmg and Laconic Droid!)

Comment: Because it is not only a great band but also a torture device. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_maiden_%28torture_device%29

Comment: Looks like the comments have been purged, but dmg and Laconic Droid did point out to me the torture device aspect of the clue, so thanks. :)